# Проблема с выборкой только уникальныйх полей и функцией CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня стоит задача: выбрать из таблицы с актерами всех актеров, которые не имеют однофамильцев.
Я делаю это следующим запросом:

```
SELECT Actors.surname FROM `Actors` GROUP BY Actors.surname HAVING COUNT(Actors.surname) = 1 order by Actors.surname
```

Соответственно я успешно получаю результат без дубликатов: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но! Мне нужно использовать функцию CONCAT что бы получить имя актера полностью, вместе с фамилией и опять же избежать всех однофамильцев. И вот это сделать у меня не выходит никак.
Можете подсказать мне с этим? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно использовать функцию CONCAT что бы получить имя актера полностью, вместе с фамилией и опять же избежать всех однофамильцев.

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT(firsname, ' ', surname)) fullname
FROM actors
GROUP BY surname
HAVING COUNT(surname) = 1
-- ORDER BY surname
```

Если only_full_group_by отключен, обёртку MAX() можно убрать.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
        SELECT * FROM `Actors` where Actors.surname in (
        SELECT Actors.surname FROM `Actors` GROUP BY Actors.surname 
        HAVING COUNT(Actors.surname) = 1 
        )
         order by Actors.surname
```

Comment: Тоже вариант, однако вложенные запросы не очень хорошо